# Check whether the string contains backslash or not?

Tags: java, string, backslash

In Java, `\'` denotes a single quotation mark (single quote) character, and `\"` denotes a double quotation mark (double quote) character.

So, `String s = "I\'m a human.";` works well.

However, `String s = "I'm a human."` does not make any compile errors, either.

Likewise, `char c = '\"';` works, but `char c = '"';` also works.

But I need to detect whether the string contains backslash or not:

1. `"abcd'"` does not contain backslash
2. `"abcd\'"` contains backslash.

I need to distinguish whether the string contains backslash or not.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Once it's a Java string the backslash is gone; it's just for Java's sake.

Comment: how about `str.indexOf("\\")`?

Comment: "abcd\'" - if this is a Java's String this doesn't contais a backslash

Comment: In your examples, the backslash is used to escape the next character; but it won't be part of the `String`.

Comment: I am taking input string from command prompt. Now, I need to check whether this input string contains backslash or not?
But the problem is if I give string as "abcd\'qwert" then I can not detect the presence of backslash. So, I want to know if there is any way to detect this presence of backslash?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The're called escape sequences for a reason. For example, `\n` once put in a String, cannot match a literal `\` against itself. It's gone. All that's left, is a new-line.

> Remember `\` is used to escape a character. It itself doesn't remain a part of the String.

However, you can check for a literal `\` by doing a simple contains like

```
String s = "abcd\\";
System.out.println(s.contains("\\"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`"abcd\"` is not a valid string in java.
Here java treated `\"` as an escape sequence character(`"`). So, if you want to put a backslash in a string then you need to use `\` with escape sequence character.

String `"abcd\'"` has not contained backslash character. It has an escape sequence character `\'`.

> Escape characters (also called escape sequences or escape codes) in
>   general are used to signal an alternative interpretation of a series
>   of characters. In Java, a character preceded by a backslash (`\`) is an
>   escape sequence and has special meaning to the java compiler.
>
> When an escape sequence is encountered in a print statement, the
>   compiler interprets it accordingly. For example, if you want to put
>   quotes within quotes you must use the escape sequence, `\"`, on the
>   interior quotes. To print the sentence: `She said "Hello!" to me.` you
>   should write:
>
> ```
> System.out.println("She said \"Hello!\" to me.");
> ```

```
// Java program to illustrate to find a character
// in the string.
import java.io.*;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    // This is a string in which a character
    // to be searched.
    String str = "gee\\k";

    // Returns index of first occurrence of character.
    int firstIndex = str.indexOf('\\');
    System.out.println("First occurrence of char '\\'" +
                    " is found at : " + firstIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string.contains("\\")){
//TODO do your code here
}
```

Comment: `contains` calls `indexOf` so, `indexOf` would be the best choice.

Comment: @GeomanYabes no it wouldn't be a better choice: one should not sacrifice readability.

Answer (score 0):

\ is used as for escape sequence in Java.

If you want to print backslash in the string you just have to print `"abcd\\".`

For your example it would be:

```
boolean containsBs = "abcd\\".contains("\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Strings you do not need to use the escape character(backslash) for single quotation marks. Likewise when using char you do not need to escape the double quotation mark.

> String use double quotation mark while chars use single quotation mark. You need to use the escape character for double quote in Strings and for simple quote in chars.

```
String ex="I'm an example";
String ex2="My name is \"example\"";
char c='"';
char c2='\'';
```

If you want to find out if a String contains backslash

```
String ex="abcd";
String ex2="abcd\\";
ex.contains("\\"); //false
ex.contains("\\"); //true
```

> The first backslash is for escaping and the second is the character.